# Асинхронная подгрузка ya-share2

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Всем привет.
В документации по блоку поделиться от Яндекса (ya-share2) отмечено, что не рекомендуется подгружать скрипт асинхронно, т.к. он может работать некорректно.

Мне необходимо вставить скрипт уже после загрузки страницы. Он работает нормально, но в консоль всегда пишет ошибку (попробовал грузить скрипт синхронно, ошибка не воспроизводится)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modName' of undefined
at Object.getMod (https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js:1:11369)
at https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js:1:13085
at Array.filter (native)
at https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js:1:13049
at https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js:15:34756
at HTMLDocument.n (https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js:15:139)
```

Кто-нибудь знает решение этой проблемы?
Спасибо

Comment: Можете привести пример разметки до инициализации блока? Есть подозрение, что блок некорректно обрабатывает посторонние классы на элементе `.ya-share2`.

Comment: Посмотрите сейчас, пожалуйста, – осталась ошибка?

Comment: Да, сейчас ошибки не возникает. Все работает как следует. Спасибо!